# Save Images, Display in Gallery App

Tags: android, image, gallery

I'm currently working on an App that receives multiple images via socket. To save them, I wrote the following methods:

```
public static boolean saveTempImageToGallery(Context c) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = c.openFileInput(Settings.TEMP_PHOTO_STORAGE);
        // create name of file: [date]-[time]-baby
        final String tFilename = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss")
                .format(new Date()) + ".png";

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "External storage available.");
            // sd card available
            File dir = getExternalStorageDir("Photos");
            if (dir.mkdirs() || dir.isDirectory()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Directory: "+dir.getAbsolutePath());
                File newImage = new File(dir, tFilename);
                if (newImage.createNewFile() && newImage.isFile()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Saving image to "+newImage.getAbsolutePath());
                    final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    // compress image to png
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, baos);
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(newImage);
                    fo.write(baos.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image saved!");
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Could not create directory.");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "External storage not available.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return false;
}

public static File getExternalStorageDir() {
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
            + Settings.EXT_STORAGE_DIRECTORY);
    return dir;
}

public static File getExternalStorageDir(String subdir) {
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
            + Settings.EXT_STORAGE_DIRECTORY + "/" + subdir);
    return dir;
}
```

After saving them, I'd like to offer the user the possibility to view them in the default gallery app. After reading some post, I adapted the following code:

```
MediaScannerConnectionClient mScanClient = new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
            @Override
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                try {
                    Log.d("onScanCompleted", uri + "success");
                    if (uri != null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (mScanCon != null)
                        mScanCon.disconnect();
                    mScanCon = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Media Scan Connected.");
                String[] files = Support.getExternalStorageDir("Photos")
                        .list();
                Log.i(TAG,
                        Support.getExternalStorageDir("Photos").list().length
                                + " elements in dir.");
                if (files.length > 0) {
                    for (String cur : files) {
                        if (cur.equals(".") || cur.equals(".."))
                            continue;
                        Log.i(TAG, "Using "
                                + cur
                                + " to scan stuff. "
                                + Support.getExternalStorageDir("Photos")
                                        .getAbsolutePath() + "/" + cur);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Not using "
                                + cur
                                + " to scan stuff. "
                                + Support.getExternalStorageDir("Photos")
                                        .toString() + "/" + cur);
                        mScanCon.scanFile(
                                Support.getExternalStorageDir("Photos")
                                        .getAbsolutePath() + "/" + cur,
                                "image/*");
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No images available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

            }
        };
        if (mScanCon != null)
            mScanCon.disconnect();
        mScanCon = new MediaScannerConnection(getApplicationContext(),
                mScanClient);
        mScanCon.connect();
```

Weird thing: Seems like onMediaScannerConnected is never fired - anyone has an idea? I've been searching the web and stackoverflow for the last hour..

Thank you.

Comment: you mean after saving in sdcard its not get visible in gallery app ?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have to connect to the media scanner to start a scan, you can use [this static method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) instead.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {dir.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
```

**edit:**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(filePath);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: But I don't want to scan my media files into android's content resolver etc, I simply want to open the gallery displaying my folder with my images. Isn't that how I am supposed to do it?

Comment: well, to show a folder I really don't know and if you find out, please let me know cause my application is only opening the last image. But to open one image, check my edited code.